# How To Get All UUID's Logged In From A Single IP (MySQL Database [Minecraft])

Tags: java, mysql, minecraft

I just need this last piece of the puzzle to finish my plugin. Currently I am having a problem with how to set up my MySQL table for all alt accounts that are logged into a server. I know that I either need to have a set number that is super high and make the uuid's add to the next empty cell or just add a new column for every uuid, but I just need to know the most efficient way to add all UUID's to a single IP (The primary key). Looks something I like at the moment:

```
 IP |  
Row #1  
Row #2
```

etc

Comment: Sorry, but this is extremely unclear and lacking any context that would allow us to help.  The fact that you are considering a new column for "every uuid" indicates that your mental model of how databases work is not correct, but it is impossible to tell what you're missing from the information in the question.  Please explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish, and show us the CREATE TABLE statements for the applicable tables.  Clarify what the uuid represents and explain what you want to do with the data.

Comment: Also, please take a few minutes to take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the IP as Primary Key. The fact that a Primary Key is unique and you have multiple occurrences of IP addresses with different UUIDs makes it hard to accomplish what you need.

Try something like this:

```
id (PK)| ip_address |   uuid   | date
--------------------------------------
 1     |  1.2.3.4   | as-df-gh | 12345
 2     |  1.2.3.4   | df-as-gh | 12346
 3     |  2.3.4.5   | as-gh-df | 12347
 4     |  3.4.5.6   | as-df-gh | 12348
```

Whenever someone logs in you can then add another row (or if you don't need the login date column, first check if there's already one with the IP / UUID pair and skip it).

Now you can select all UUIDs from a certain IP address:

```
SELECT uuid FROM your_table WHERE ip_address = '1.2.3.4'
```

results in

```
  uuid
--------
as-df-gh
df-as-gh
```

Or the other way around:

```
SELECT ip_address FROM your_table WHERE uuid = 'as-df-gh'
```

results in

```
ip_address
----------
 1.2.3.4
 3.4.5.6
```

Comment: I didn't think about the table being set up like this and I think I will use this version.